# ¿Cómo Obtener Token en Solicitud a Rest Api?

Tags: c#

Ejecuto una solicitud a una Rest Api y me devuelve codigo 200 OK, es decir que está bien pero no sé cómo obtener el token que devuelve

Mi codigo

```
public async Task PostParametrizadoAsync()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token");
            var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "api-stag"));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "fsf3242@stag.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr"));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "fsdfs34234"));
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", ""));
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            richTextBox1.Text = response.ToString();
        }
```

Me devuelve

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  CF-RAY: 3c99d07f6d3d50c8-MIA
  Date: Thu, 07 Dec 2017 19:15:35 GMT
  Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dfca86d4feeaaaabb7395544081a3d8f61512674135; expires=Fri, 07-Dec-18 19:15:35 GMT; path=/; domain=.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr; HttpOnly
  Server: cloudflare-nginx
  X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo esperas que te llegue ese token, por medio del `response`, como `header`?

Comment: El token lo devuelven en un json

Comment: Intenta leer la respuesta con fiddler o PostMan

Answer (score 0):

El token suele estar en

```
response.Content
```

Es decir en el body del response. Allí está el json que esperas.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarás crear un `CookieContainer` para recibir los *cookies*, algo similar a:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
(...etc...)
```

Intenta con este código, sustituyendo los datos privados que espera tu servidor por los valores correctos:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
        
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token");
        var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "api-stag"));
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "fsf3242@stag.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr"));
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "fsdfs34234"));
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", ""));
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token").Result;

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
        IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri);
        foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
            Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
        
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

Si pruebas este código de aquí abajo, tendrás un ejemplo práctico que funciona.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://google.com").Result;

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
        IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri);
        Console.WriteLine("Cookies");
        foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
            Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Respuesta:");
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

La respuesta que te enviará a la consola será similar a esta:

```
Cookies

    NID: 215=UKQ5UQ7uZVjuW9cI1iwCtTkYy7Alk69OW2iyUEAOUfaT_JgBzYZJUwr9NZLmnqXoZRlxTddxVQqvkT4omciSWjimkpARqXTi3grSWtQiRRXO9_u0tW3Fl3URd7Cd7W3lmhYqiwPdsxtj5fh5bDE6GRWcVMlKgfYYCZkl092eRA8
    Respuesta:
    StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
    {
      Date: Mon, 17 May 2021 14:46:05 GMT
      Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
      P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
      Server: gws
      X-XSS-Protection: 0
      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
      Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2021-05-17-14; expires=Wed, 16-Jun-2021 14:46:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure
      Set-Cookie: NID=215=UKQ5UQ7uZVjuW9cI1iwCtTkYy7Alk69OW2iyUEAOUfaT_JgBzYZJUwr9NZLmnqXoZRlxTddxVQqvkT4omciSWjimkpARqXTi3grSWtQiRRXO9_u0tW3Fl3URd7Cd7W3lmhYqiwPdsxtj5fh5bDE6GRWcVMlKgfYYCZkl092eRA8; expires=Tue, 16-Nov-2021 14:46:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
      Accept-Ranges: none
      Vary: Accept-Encoding
      Transfer-Encoding: chunked
      Expires: -1
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    }
```